# How to download multiple files stored in database as bytes

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am storing files in database in the form of bytes. We have requirement to download all attachments as zip file. Please suggest

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void ZipDownload()
    {
        var list = //query for getting the files.
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
        foreach (var file in list)
        {

            zip.AddEntry(file.docname, (byte[])file.doc.ToArray());
        }
        var zipMs = new MemoryStream();
        zip.Save(zipMs);
        byte[] fileData = zipMs.GetBuffer();
        zipMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        zipMs.Flush();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=docs.zip ");
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
        Response.End();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks VVN its working. However its throwing out of memory exception if zip size is more than 500 mb